# Несколько объявлений для одного атрибута импорта C#

Tags: c#, атрибуты, dllimport

Существует ли способ для одного атрибута в C# объявить несколько методов, то есть сократить количество импортов одного Dll файла в последней версии языка?

Я думаю, код тогда будет выглядеть приятнее.

Comment: импорт библиотеки совершается один раз независимо от того, сколько раз вы имортировали ее методы в текущей сборке.

Comment: Да, но хотелось бы уменьшить количество строк, да и читабельность увеличить с помощью этого (если возможно)...

Comment: Вынесите все импорты в отдельный статический `internal static` класс например `NativeMethods`, который не придется читать часто. То что вы спрашиваете, сделать нельзя.

Comment: Хм, хорошо...

Получается, множественный импорт сделать невозможно?

Comment: `множественный импорт сделать невозможно?` в разработке нет ничего невозможного, но даже если это возможно, в этом нет совершенно никакого смысла.

Comment: Кодогенерация может помочь.